# Is the given Ring $\mathcal K(U)$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, ring-theory

Let $U$ be a bounded open disk in $\mathbb C$ and $\mathcal K(U)$ denote the ring of complex analytic function on $U$.

1. Is $\mathcal K(U)$ an integral domain .
2. Give an example of a maximal ideal in $\mathcal K(U)$.

In first part we need only to show that $\mathcal K(U)$ is a without zero divisor.

Please give me hint how to show that this ring is a without zero divisor.

Thank you.

Comment: For a maximal ideal, try finding a surjective morphism $\mathcal K(U)\to \mathbb C$ and determine its kernel.

Comment: If $fg=0$ on a disk and neither is zero, then at least one of them must be zero on "most" of the disk. Show that this is impossible (think what happens if $f,g$ are polynomials).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: complex analytic functions are locally power series. Show that the ring of formal power series over $\Bbb C$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: @ Mike : any example of maximal ideal

Comment: @user120386 For this one too, thinking in terms of power series will give you the right idea.